# MySQL 'localhost' database is very slow running on InnoDB engine. Switched to MyISAM and its 20x faster. But what engine is the best for my data?

Tags: python, mysql

Question in the bottom of the post.

I'm on Windows 10. Using MySQL Workbench 8.0CE.

Data is 1014 rows of movie manuscripts.

20x faster is meant literally. It went from 40 minutes on InnoDB, to 2 minutes on MyISAM, running this following python script.

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import pymysql
import traceback
import logging
from tqdm import tqdm

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

mysql_code = "password"

def getData(id, script_raw):
    #print(script_raw)
    script_clean = remove_html_tags(script_raw).replace("'","''")
    #output_str = ''.join(c for c in script_clean if c.isprintable())
    #print(output_str)
    #print(script_clean_2)
    save_data(script_clean, id)

def remove_html_tags(text):
    """Remove html tags from a string"""
    import re
    clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
    return re.sub(clean, '', text)

def save_data(script_clean, id):
    try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='admin',
                               passwd=mysql_code, db='manuscriptproject')
        cur = conn.cursor()

        query = "UPDATE `clean_movie_script` SET `script_clean` = '%s'  WHERE (`id` = '%s');"
        final_query = query % (script_clean, id)

        cur.execute(final_query)
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info("Error with query for id : " + str(id))
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
        logging.error(e)

def get_non_populated_records():
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='admin',
                               passwd=mysql_code, db='manuscriptproject')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "SElECT id, script FROM `movie_script` "
        "WHERE script IS NOT NULL "
        "ORDER BY id asc "
        "LIMIT 100000")
    data = list(cur.fetchall())
    conn.close()
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":

    unpopulated_records = get_non_populated_records()

    for x in tqdm(unpopulated_records):
        try:
            getData(x[0], x[1])
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Switching from InnoDB to MyISAM it changed the way it defines my 'id' column from an INT with PK, NN, Unique, and Autoincrement enabled to an INT with only NN enabled, and a default expression of '0'. I also cannot change the engine back to InnoDB now.

Question: I'm trying to understand which engine is the best for my use case. 2 minutes still seems slow for a 200MB database. Searching online, InnoDB should be faster than MyISAM, and it might have something to do with how I define my 'id' column maybe - I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: I sat with this all day yesterday and this morning too. I don't know why, but I just managed to run my python script in 4 seconds as I would expect, using InnoDB. I created a new table, copied all the data over from the old table, and ran it. Very confused, but now it works.

Comment: I would guess you had some other resource-intensive apps running on your Windows machine at the same time, slowing everything down. I once supported a customer who complained their database on Windows Server slowed to a crawl after 10 minutes. When they checked on it, it would become fast again. It turned out they were using the 3D graphic screensaver (and in those days the server had no GPU to speed up graphics, so the screensaver was stealing CPU resources).

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in both formats -- MyISAM and InnoDB.  There are likely to be subtle things to discuss.

Comment: Also, what percent of the rows had `script` being `NOT NULL`?

Comment: I figure the reason it was slow, was that I had run another script a few times and forgot to close the connection. So it must have had like 20 connections open and unused. I don't know if it takes up resources, but its the only thing that can make sense of it, so I guess it does even when not used, or at least limits bandwidth to 1/20th. I re-created an InnoDB table and restarted my PC due to an update, and that's when I went straight back and ran the script above again. Finally it only took 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Do this only once for the entire program:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(...)
```

(It may be the most costly part of the task, and the code *seems* to do it inside a loop.)

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely a bit clumsy of me